# Angular getter in template expression using dynamic variable

Tags: angular, typescript

Assume I have an Angular (6+) component like the following:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '{{test}}'
})
export class MyComponent {
    test = 'myData';

    constructor() {}

    get myData(): string {
        return 'this is what I want so see in the template';
    }
}
```

This is a very simplistic view of what I'm trying to achieve, but basically, if my template was `{{myData}}` I would see my getter function being called and output the expected string. But if the getter function name to be called is held in another variable in the component (imagine in my real world scenario that I have an array of these), is there a way to tell Angular to call the respective getter whose name is held by the variable test above?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `{{this[test]}}` is working.

Comment: nice question and answer. seems like you knew answer all along, but its good to know this kind of thing works.

Comment: I was thinking of deleting the answer, but really, it came to me a few minutes after I posted to try it. Not trying to show off or anything, but I think it may help others.

Comment: This is really more of a comment, I would say flesh the answer out a bit or remove it and add a comment

Comment: I'll leave it to the moderators to decide. Either way, I think it's good to know that you can use `this` in an Angular template, where normally you wouldn't.

Comment: my question is why [test]  or ['myData'] works? what relation does this[] have with getters? any source to read would be appreciated.

Comment: @Vato In my component I have an array of fields and values. In my template I iterate over every field with an `*ngFor` and output either directly the value of the field in the object or the returned value from a custom getter. I guess there are other ways to do this, but in my particular example it's the most elegant.

Comment: @Vato getters are a feature of JavaScript, not Angular. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get